# python - using regex and capture groups in next method

Tags: python, regex

I need help with this one:

1. I open file, use readlines method to create a list out of it.
2. I need to find first occurrence of patern/match and assign first capture group to variable

   ```
   list = ['firstString','xxxSTATUS=100','thirdString','fourthString']
   value = next(x for x in list if [re.search('.*STATUS=(.*)', x)])
   ```

if I assign it to 'value' as it is, I get 'xxxSTATUS=100' (string type), BUT if I do it like so:

```
  value = next(x for x in list if [re.search('.*STATUS=(.*)', x).group(1)])
```

I get:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Obviously I can't do value.group(1) as it is string and not regex object. I also get (it is my assumption) that at the time I'm using regex pattern, my variable is still of no type,because it wasn't assigned yet.

**So my question is how to solve this issue and assign capture group eg. '100' to variable.** Is there any workaround?

Comment: Do you mean you need `value = next(re.search('STATUS=(.*)', x).group(1) for x in list if re.search('STATUS=(.*)', x))` to return just `100`? Also, why not just iterate over the list and grab the first one matching the pattern? See https://ideone.com/BNb2I9

Comment: Yes, that was exactly it. Thank you very much! Now I see where was the mistake. Could you please make your comment an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` error just means you got no match and tried to access group contents of a null object.

I think the easiest way is to iterate over the list items searching for the match, and once found, get Group 1 contents and assign them to `value`:

```
import re
list = ['firstString','xxxSTATUS=100','thirdString','fourthString']
value = ""
for x in list:
    m = re.search('STATUS=(.*)', x)
    if m:
        value = m.group(1)
        break

print(value)
```

Note you do not need the initial `.*` in the pattern as `re.search` pattern is not anchored at the start of the string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BNb2I9)

Also, if you want your initial approach to work, you need to check if there is a match first with `if re.search('STATUS=(.*)', x)`, and then run it again to get the group contents with `re.search('STATUS=(.*)', x).group(1)`:

```
value = next(re.search('STATUS=(.*)', x).group(1) for x in list if re.search('STATUS=(.*)', x))
```