# re.search group not working in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to analyze some logs from a text file containing my ping information.

Here is a small example of the text file output:

```
[2020-06-01 21:54:15.924620] 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.029 ms
[2020-06-01 21:54:16.968341] 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.078 ms
```

I wrote a small python regex script to extract the time from the time=x.xxx ms part:

```
with open("ping_test.txt",'r') as fp: 
    for line in fp:       
        line = line.strip() 
        print(re.search(r'time=(\d.\d*)',line).group(1))
```

Expected output: x.xxx

Actual output: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

I have attempted debugging by doing the following: `print(re.search(r'time=(\d.\d*)',line))`
to which an example output would be: `<re.Match object; span=(85, 95), match='time=0.032'>`

This shows that re.search is indeed finding a match. What I don't understand is why I can't call the .group() method to output my desired group.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check if there is a match first. `'NoneType' object has no attr` means your regex did not found any match. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394614/python-using-regex-and-capture-groups-in-next-method/41394786#41394786). Also, fix your regex, it must be `r'time=(\d+\.\d+)'` or `r'time=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)'`

Comment: Can you try print(type(re.search(r'time=(\d.\d*)',line))) ?

Comment: does ALL line have this info ?

Comment: Try to add `if line:` to skip empty lines.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried doing that by printing the object without the .group() and I get `match='time=0.023`

Comment: do `if not re.search(r'time=(\d.\d*)',line):print(line)` to get the wrong ones

Comment: @azro That's something I didn't account for, some lines may have no match indeed. Theoretically speaking they should all be the same. I will try try except

Comment: That means use my solution. Check if there is a match before accessing the `.group()` or `.group(1)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone, it turns out that one of the lines returned a connection error, and therefore was returning a nontype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just try to print also the lines that do not have a match. For example:

```py
with open("ping_test.txt",'r') as fp: 
    for line in fp:       
        res = re.search(r'time=(\d.\d*)',line.strip())
        if res:
            print(res.group(1))
        else:
            print('Error while parsing:', line)
```